# Options for ASP.NET page with matching client-side and server-side markup?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

Suppose I'm building a StackOverflow clone using webforms ASP.NET and jQuery. The Question page has a question, several answers, and comments under each. Requirements:

1. Users can post new answers and comments, and edit existing ones, without postbacks.
2. No UpdatePanels; the AJAX calls retrieve just the JSON they need, not HTML fragments.
3. The page loads with all existing answers and comments in place (no javascript needs to run to read the page).

What I'm trying to figure out is how to do this without having to maintain two sets of markup (one that's bound on the client using some form of jQuery templating, and one that's bound on the server using traditional WebForms).

What are my options?

Comment: +1 good question, I also have the same problem, but dont know the solution yet, whenever I need to change something in the page, I change that in both `aspx page` as well as `html template`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not exactly what you asked for you may want to consider rendering the HTML on the server via a service (not using update panel) and sending it to the client instead of using client templates. It couldn't be that bad because Facebook are doing it:
http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=596368660334
If it is suitable in your situation depends on how rich your markup is and what percentage of the data sent over the wire will be markup as opposed to content.

Comment: I think this is probably the smartest approach. Unfortunately it looks like FB took the video down before I had a chance to watch the whole thing, any idea if it's available elsewhere?

Comment: N/M - found it here: http://www.livestream.com/facebookhq/video?clipId=pla_89900c3b-ed61-457a-a571-4c7cfbcf2234&utm_source=lslibrary&utm_medium=ui-thumb

Comment: The most relevant part to this issue is an audience question around 40:55.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't use jQuery but the [Spark](http://sparkviewengine.com) view engine provides a `JavascriptViewResult` class that allows you to render templates on the client as well as on the server. This is intended for the exact situation that you describe. See [this post](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/03/12/client-rendering-views-with-spark-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx) by K. Scott Allen for a simple explanation of how this works.

You can then use the same View page on the server and the client. On the server you pass a viewmodel object to the view and on the client you pass it a JSON object. You can even include code in your views as long as it is valid code for both the C# and JavaScript languages.
For example `var x = 1;` will compile in both C# and Javascript.

Comment: So how do you use Spark and JavaScriptViewResult in WebForms?

Comment: You don't, it works for MVC. Sorry, missed that word in your question. I find WebForms to be completely unsuitable for the kind of solution that you are looking for so I kind of just assumed MVC.
It is possible to mix Web Forms and MVC together in the same project so it would still be possible to use an MVC controller and view for this part of your app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is potentially an option, but this becomes relatively trivial using ASP.net MVC.  You have a partial view for an answer, for example, and this is part of the markup on the page.  You then also have an action on your controller that takes e.g. an answer id, that just returns the rendered html from that partial view, which can then be slotted into the document.

I've used this in a few places and find it to be a very clean method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [javscriptdotnet](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/) in combinations with [embeddedjs](http://embeddedjs.com/)

That way you would be able to reuse the same templates in both places.

Personally, I think this is usually an overkill. You would be introducing lots of dependencies which are hard to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format` JavaScript method which is defined in the scripts loaded by ScriptManager (or look for an alternative implementation [here](http://www.masterdata.dyndns.org/r/string_format_for_javascript/)). It's an analogue of `String.Format` .Net method.

```
string CommentTpl = "<div class='comment {0}'>{1}</div>";
```

With `String.format` you can render this template on both the client and the server. Just don't forget to properly escape it for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a template html file and load it from JavaScript and from the server? In JavaScript, you get the HTML template once for all items it's used on (store it in a variable or something).

You can then do string replacements in both and you're good to go with only one place to make HTML updates.

Answer (score 0):

**Ditch all the controls in ASP.NET** and use only HTML markup with Javascript and CSS.

[ASP.NET abstracts the presentation layer](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/42/aspnet-is-a-leaky-abstraction#toc-leaky-abstractions-lead-to-productivity-loss-and-unnecessary-trade-offs) away from developers, however the good news is that you dont have to use web controls in to write a beautiful website using .NET. Read further down the post: "[don’t throw the baby (.NET) out with the bath water (ASP.NET)](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/42/aspnet-is-a-leaky-abstraction#toc-dont-use-asp-net-but-dont-throw-the-baby-net-out-with-the-bath-water-asp-net)".

You can still retain .NET for passing bits of information between the front-end and the database (using JSON not Postbacks) and handling other bits of logic like security and login that cant be handled by the client.

Keep it simple while still adding markup dynamically so that your page loads with content automatically, such as follows:

```
<% foreach (Post post in PostList) { %>
<h2><%= post.Title %></h2>
<p><%= post.Content %></p>
<% } %>
```

Basically, keep the middle tier to the minimum (for example using ashx "Generic Handlers" instead of aspx "Pages" wherever possible) if you dont want to start getting confused with gratuitous ASP.NET markup and adding bloatware like ViewState.